# URL routing in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have a ApplicationController class with an action called Admin

so my url is   **www.mysite.com/Application/Admin**

is there anyway i can have the routing be **www.mysite.com/Admin**  and go to this method.

i know i can do this by creating an **AdminController** but for this one function i thought it was easier to just put in another controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this above your default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ShortRoute",
    "{action}",
    new { controller = "Application", action = "Index"}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `Application` controller and the `Admin` method as the default controller and action, using *parameter defaults*:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Application", action = "Admin" }
);
```

If this is your last route, it will match any request that does not have a controller name and an action name in it. In this particular example, even a request without an action will execute your `Admin` action, since it's the default action.

Note that routes with parameter defaults can create strange behavior in your existing routes, if you have any. You can always use the [ASP.NET MVC Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) to test which routes match a given URL.

Comment: @Robert This *is* the new route. :)

Comment: I don't think this one will match mysite.com/action.

Comment: +1 for the route debugger.  Everyone who programs in ASP.NET MVC should know about it, and the [NerdDinner tutorial.](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm)